# How to read a hash value and get the corresponding AccountId from Substrate using RPC call?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I have a substrate node up and running with storage item as: `value(Hash): Option<AccountId>`. My aim is to provide the hash value (say, `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` and get the corresponding account id in return).

When I do this through the UI, I get the following:
[image]

I want to perform the same task via RPC calls. After going through [this](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/) blog post, I realized that my case would be to read the `StorageMaps` and so I began with running a few queries. If I am not wrong, the module is `Substratekitties` and the storage item is `value`. The mapping would be `value` to `AccountId`.

I ran the first two calls:

```
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("Substratekitties", 128)
"0xe4a154b5ba85d6072b187ee66e4fef05"
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("Value", 128)
"0x6b2f21989c43cc4e06ac1ad3e2027000"
```

But I am confused in the third call encoding: encoding the file sha256 hash. How to do that?
Running `util_crypto.blake2AsHex("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", 256)
"0x16821de47d8b3b0fa4ca43e5db1028d75207cbd1c379a4738144972b105355aa"`
 won't work and is not working either.

By not working I mean, I get the "null" values when executing this query.
This is the storage struct:

```
use frame_support::{decl_module, decl_storage, dispatch::result::Result, ensure, StorageMap};
use frame_system::ensure_signed;
use sp_runtime::DispatchError;

// pub trait Trait: balances::Trait {}
pub trait Trait: pallet_balances::Trait {}

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as KittyStorage {
        // Value: map T::Hash => Option<T::AccountId>;
        // TODO: check whether this is the appropriate datatype(hash).
        Value: map hasher(blake2_256) T::Hash => Option<T::AccountId>;
        // Balances: map hasher(blake2_256) (T::AssetId, T::AccountId) => T::Balance;
    }
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        fn set_value(origin, value: T::Hash) -> Result<(), DispatchError> {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(!<Value<T>>::contains_key(value), "key already exists");
            <Value<T>>::insert(value, sender);
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
My literal query:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getStorage", "params": ["0x3fd011a1ea758d2e1b46ed3cec43fc86b2f21989c43cc4e06ac1ad3e2027000d3585436436a2253c5163fa0cfe54a648fa533ef32ea10dbd966ac438af77b71"]}' http://localhost:9933/
```

Hex queries:

```
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("KittyStorage", 128)
"0xe3fd011a1ea758d2e1b46ed3cec43fc8"
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("Value", 128)
"0x6b2f21989c43cc4e06ac1ad3e2027000"
util_crypto.blake2AsHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001234")

"0xd3585436436a2253c5163fa0cfe54a648fa533ef32ea10dbd966ac438af77b71"
```

Comment: What is "not working"? You need to share some reproducible error. It would also help to share your storage declaration.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, I have updated the question with the storage struct and explaining what's not working

Comment: You still have not shared your literal query....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is you are taking the hash of a string "0000...0001" not the bytes. Try adding `0x` to the front of the string.

EDIT: Try like this:

```
util_crypto.blake2AsHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")

> "0x33e423980c9b37d048bd5fadbd4a2aeb95146922045405accc2f468d0ef96988"
```

EDIT 2: The other issue here is that you are using the wrong key.

Your example shows you are taking the storage key "Substratekitties" but your storage key is `KittyStorage` as specified in the `decl_storage!` macro.

So your first hash should be: `0xe3fd011a1ea758d2e1b46ed3cec43fc8`

Comment: I added `0x` and even then the result is null.

Comment: Then convert the string to u8a first with `hexToU8a`. See my updated answer

Comment: One more error I caught, and edited my answer again.

Comment: I tried the query: `➜  ~ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getStorage", "params": ["0x3fd011a1ea758d2e1b46ed3cec43fc86b2f21989c43cc4e06ac1ad3e2027000d3585436436a2253c5163fa0cfe54a648fa533ef32ea10dbd966ac438af77b71"]}' http://localhost:9933/` and got the result: `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}`

Comment: The params for the above were derived as:
```
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("KittyStorage", 128)
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("Value", 128)
util_crypto.blake2AsHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001234")
```
Yes, the hex value does exist on blockchain.

Comment: You are _at least_ missing an `e` in the beginning of your hex for `KittyStorage`

Comment: Glad to help. I hope now you can see that providing **all** the details of your setup can help track the problem. (1) The storage name as declared in `decl_storage`. (2) The strings you were using to do the hashing. (3) the final RPC call you made. Please take a look at the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide and hopefully it will make solving problems easier the next time! :)